# jQuery validation: Custom rule not called

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Here is my simple validation code for testing:

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("oneTypeChecked", function (value, element) {
        return false; //$(':checkbox:checked') > 0
    }, "Check one or more type");

    $("#RequestCreateForm").validate({
        rules: {
            ChkBoxType1: { oneTypeChecked: true }
        }
    });
```

But my method oneTypeChecked is never called when I submit form.
Why?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input type="checkbox" id="ChkBoxType2" name="requestTypeIds2" value="2">Type 2     
    <input type="checkbox" id="ChkBoxType1" name="requestTypeIds1" value="1">Type 1        
    <input type="checkbox" id="ChkBoxType3" name="requestTypeIds3" value="3">Type 3
</div>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you also post your html markup? is it possible that there isn't an element called 'ChkBoxType' in your markup?

Comment: Validation is not standard out of the box -- which plugin are you using.

Comment: @Hogan: I'm using jQuery validation plug-in 1.6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

validation plugin works according to the **name** attribute and not id. try changing the name attribute on your input.

Answer (score 2):

with this html

```
<form id="RequestCreateForm" action="" method="post">
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="checkbox" class="oneTypeChecked" name="requestTypeIds2" value="2">Type 2     
        <input type="checkbox" class="oneTypeChecked" name="requestTypeIds1" value="1">Type 1       
        <input type="checkbox" class="oneTypeChecked" name="requestTypeIds3" value="3">Type 3
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and this jquery

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("oneTypeChecked", function(value, element) {
    return $('.oneTypeChecked:checked') > 0
}, "Check one or more type");

$("#RequestCreateForm").validate({
    rules: {
        ChkBoxType1: {
            oneTypeChecked: true
        }
    }
});
```

you will get the result you want

here is a [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/UDASh/)

Comment: after hours of seraching why my custom validation doesn't work, your solution finally showed me, I hadn't added the method name to the class of the input. thanks! None of the other examples show this crucial step

Comment: I'm happy this helped you, have a great day

Comment: Thanks.. spent more than 4 hours on this issue, and finally it came down to this! Thanks Man.. this is absolute brilliant

Comment: glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, if you don't add in the required it will be valid because it is not checked.

```
    rules: {   
        ChkBoxType1: { required : true, oneTypeChecked: true }
    }
```

Comment: No, what is required is that at least one checkbox must be required, not only the 'ChkBoxType1'