# jQuery validation custom validator not fired even though name is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<form id="myTestFrom">
  <input type="text" name="test_txb" id="test_txb" value="" class="form-control" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

  $.validator.addMethod('testValidationMethod', function (value, element) {
    alert('FIRED');
  }, 'test error message');

  $('#myTestFrom').validate({
    rules: {
      /* (*) */
      test_txb: { testValidationMethod: true }
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is simple: my custom validator method never gets called.

I have read several similar questions and answers here on StackOverflow (for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6021262/4205470)), but none of them seemed to work. In fact, right the opposite. Most of them suggested that the jQuery validator works by looking for input fields with the specified *name*, not the specified *id*. That is, the object property name at `(*)` must match the `name` attribute of the input to be validated. However, as you can see in my code, I *do* have the `test_txb` name (as well as id) on my input, but for some reason, my validator method never gets called using the code above.

However, if I add the name of the validator method (`testValidationMethod`) as a **class** to my input field, then it does get called. This sounds contradictionary to whatever I have read here on SO since all those answers stated that the default behaviour is that the validator inspects the `name` attributes of elements when setting up custom validation rules.

So what is going on here, could someone please explain? The simplest solution would certainly be to just add the aforementioned class name but I hate littering my code with otherwise unnecessary stuff especially if I don't fully understand the reason of why I should do that.

**Edit:** jQuery validator version is 1.15.1

**Edit 2:** I also have ASP.NET MVC Unobtrusive lib referenced, maybe that conflits with something?

Comment: Ding, ding, ding.... your "edit 2" is the root cause.  You can't call `.validate()` more than once.  Since unobtrusive automatically constructs and calls `.validate()`, your instance is totally ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around in the source code of the validator plugin I've figured out that the problem was caused by the following lines:

```
// Check if a validator for this form was already created
var validator = $.data( this[ 0 ], "validator" );
if ( validator ) {
    return validator;
}
```

So the reason that any answers posted here stated that they could get it working is that they initialized the validator themselves. Probably I got this weird behavior because the ASP.NET unobtrusive library silently initialized the validator and thus even though I passed my rules into the `validate` method, nothing got added and I got back the preconfigured validator object (ugh, the downside of automated stuff...).

I finally got it working by using the post-initialization rule addition like so:

```
$('#test_txb').rules('add', {
  testValidationMethod: true
});
```

Comment: You can't call `.validate()` more than once.  Since unobtrusive already constructs and calls `.validate()`, your instance is totally ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Have you add the plugin for validation using by jquery ?

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-validate

Because I have no problem with your solution when I copied/paste it inside codepen.

edit: I think you should have a return value for a validator

edit 2: regarding to your edit, I searched on google and found something that seems interesting, link belove:

https://www.tigraine.at/2011/08/26/jquery-validate-and-microsofts-unobtrusive-validation-dont-play-well-together

Comment: Yes, I have added otherwise I wouldn't even be able to reference the validator field on `$`. About the return value, I have tried it like that too and it still does not get called and adding a return value would not explain why it does get called if I add the mentioned class name anyway.

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot to include `js` of validation or jQuery
Here is your working code

**html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myTestFrom">
      <input type="text" name="test_txb" id="test_txb" value="" class="form-control" />
</form>
```

**JavaSript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.validator.addMethod('testValidationMethod', function(value, element) {
    console.log('FIRED');
  }, 'test error message');

  $('#myTestFrom').validate({
    rules: {
      test_txb: {
        required: true,
        testValidationMethod: true
      }
    }
  });

});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gopaljoshi73/qzs5zo34/1/)